# Neural network: what does it mean if my batch_size is affecting the accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, updatebatchsize

I keep hearing that batch_size does not influence the accuracy or quality of learning.

But in my simple model, using a batch_size of 20,000 (total dataset 2.5 million) right away gives me a loss of NaN and 0.004 accuracy.
Decreasing the bath_size to 2,000 will give me a loss of 4.10 and accuracy of 0.07, and the accuracy continues to increase appropriately with each epoch as expected.

So: does the fact that my batch_size affects the accuracy mean that my model is set up wrong?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(26, activation='relu', input_dim=X.shape[1]))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy',])

model.fit(X, Y,epochs=15,batch_size=2000)
score = model.evaluate(X, Y, batch_size=2000)
score

Epoch 1/15
44s - loss: 4.7164 - acc: 0.0781
Epoch 2/15
45s - loss: 4.3305 - acc: 0.0977
Epoch 3/15
45s - loss: 4.1886 - acc: 0.1065
Epoch 4/15
45s - loss: 4.1235 - acc: 0.1104
Epoch 5/15
45s - loss: 4.0881 - acc: 0.1122
Epoch 6/15
45s - loss: 4.0657 - acc: 0.1136
Epoch 7/15
45s - loss: 4.0506 - acc: 0.1148
Epoch 8/15
45s - loss: 4.0393 - acc: 0.1154
Epoch 9/15
47s - loss: 4.0305 - acc: 0.1159
Epoch 10/15


model.fit(X, Y,epochs=15,batch_size=200000)
score = model.evaluate(X, Y, batch_size=200000)
score

Epoch 1/15
42s - loss: NaN - acc: 0.0004
```

Comment: Because of "Nan", it makes me believe that batch size is just overflowing something and causing an error.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "overflowing something". Is this a problem with my network, Keras, or neural networks in general?  That is, sometimes batch-size will in fact affect the quality of learning (in other words, if you get no loss function your accuracy is going to be way off)

Comment: Try increasing the batch gradually, until the maximum you can achieve without getting a "nan". I'm not sure, but I suspect it's too much data for a single pass and the memory/architecture/whatever can't support that much.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I have been doing. I just wanted reassurances that this behavior is normal--seeing NaN and accuracies of essentially 0 when using larger batch-sizes.  I had been led to believe that batch-size makes no difference in terms of your final accuracy, but it seems to me that it very much does.

Comment: Don't mistake "a computer error" with "batches affect the result".

Comment: "batch_size does not influence the accuracy or quality of learning" is not a very good statement, it is much too general. In an ideal scenario, yes, no matter the batch size you should eventually get the same accuracy, but nothing is ever ideal. Training on batches rather than on individual samples is an optimization and does affect the way training proceeds. The goal of it is to make your gradient learning more general, less dependent on each individual sample's features. So depending on your training strategy batch size can and will affect quality of learning.

Comment: That said, the fact that you are getting NaN from your loss function is indicative of a deeper underlying problem. For starters, if you are getting a NaN loss it means your are not learning anything, since NaN cannot be minimized. You need to figure out why you are getting NaN at certain batch size and not at smaller batches. Could be a memory issue as Daniel seems to suggest. But I would guess this is the result of some inconsistency in your training data, that only shows up once you start looking at large enough batch at once.